# How to take input in shell while waiting for timer to finish?

Tags: python

I am writing a music player using python. Right now I get the length of the song, in seconds, and use that length in a time.sleep() function. The issue with this is I cannot use commands to stop, pause, skip, etc. songs in the python shell.

I have the program working besides being able to take input. Is there a way to have the program continue working the way it does and add the ability to take input? I essentially just need to replace my "time.sleep(song length)" with a timer that doesn't stop input to the shell.

P.S. Sorry about lack of white space, I had bad habits.

Thanks.

```
# import libs
import os
import pygame
from mutagen.mp3 import MP3
import time
import random

usedAlbums = []
usedSongs = []
VOL = 1
MUSICDIR = '/home/pi/MusicPlayer/Pi/All Songs/'
os.chdir(MUSICDIR)
albums = os.listdir(MUSICDIR)
random.shuffle(albums)
pygame.mixer.pre_init(frequency=22050, size=-16, channels=2, buffer=4096)

# define funcs
def addAlbum():

    currentAlbum = albums[album]

    if currentAlbum in usedAlbums:
        addAlbum()
    else:
        usedAlbums.append(currentAlbum)

    return currentAlbum

def addSong():

    currentSong = songs[song]

    if currentSong in usedSongs:
        addSong()
    else:
         usedSongs.append(currentSong)

    return currentSong

# begin main code
print("~" * 80)
for album in range(len(albums)):
    # get new or starter album(s)
    currentAlbum = addAlbum()
    os.chdir(currentAlbum)
    songs = os.listdir(MUSICDIR + currentAlbum + "/")
    random.shuffle(songs)
    song = 0
    for song in range(len(songs)):
        # get new or starter song(s)
        currentSong = addSong()
        songinfo = MP3(currentSong)
        pygame.mixer.init(frequency=songinfo.info.sample_rate, size=-16, channels=2, buffer=4096)
        pygame.mixer.music.set_volume(VOL)
        pygame.mixer.music.load(currentSong)
        pygame.mixer.music.play()
        # print info
        print("Total Songs Played:", len(usedSongs))
        print("Album:             ", currentAlbum)
        print("Album Songs:       ", len(songs))
        print("Song:              ", currentSong[:-4])
        print("Song Number:       ", song + 1)
        print("Songs Left:        ", len(songs) - (song + 1))
        print("Duration:          ", str(int(songinfo.info.length // 60)) + ":%02d" % int(songinfo.info.length % 60))
        print("~" * 80)
        time.sleep(songinfo.info.length)
    os.chdir(MUSICDIR)
```

Comment: What library are you using for the music player? Maybe it has a built in function.

Comment: Pygame to play the music. I also have os, MP3 from mutagen.mp3, and random. I doubt those ones are any help though.I have read through the pygame docs, though may have missed something, I actually wrote all this code a while ago, I stopped once I had it working, but now I want to do more with it.